# Receiving e-mails sent to a similar e-mail account

Tags: email, gmail, imap

I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask the question, but here it is...

My sister, named say... "Foo Bar" live in Portugal and has a gmail account under the address:

FooBar@gmail.com

It is already known to my sister that another person living in Brazil and with name "Foo Bar Baz" has a gmail account under the address:

Foo.Bar@gmail.com

My sister is receiving messages to both e-mail adresses, her's (FooBar@gmail.com) and the Brazilian woman (Foo.Bar@gmail.com). This already goes on for years, since 2014 (or soo...).

If you didn't notice the address difference, it is the dot "."...

As far as i know, my sister does not have any e-mail alias that may causing the issue.

My sister do not know personally the Brazilian counterpart, however she manage to had a chat (messenger) with her a long time ago about this issue.

It is understandable that the Brazilian woman don't want to change her e-mail now, since chances are the e-mail (Foo.Bar@gmail.com) is being used in her communications and other online activities

My sister received in her email account (FooBar@gmail.com) what looks like an urgent e-email to that Brazilian woman with address (Foo.Bar@gmail.com). My sister has tried to forward it from FooBar@gmail.com to Foo.Bar@gmail.com, only to receive it back.

So my question.
What is going on?
Is it a DNS issue? A Google issue? A SMTP issue?

What to do to stop the madness? Should my sister contact Google support? If yes, how? Or there is some gmail account configuration to prevent this, so both receive their correct e-mails?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `FooBar@gmail.com` and `Foo.Bar@gmail.com` are exactly the same email address.  Additionally, `F.o.o.B.a.r@gmail.com` is also `FooBar@gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you Ramhound.
Seems you are right!

Answer (score 2):

For gmail, Foo.Bar@gmail.com and FooBar@gmail.com is the same account. Your sister may try logging into the account foo.bar@gmail.com and she should be able to do this with her password. These are the same accounts. How does she know that another woman in Brazil uses the same account?

Comment: @John - You are mistaken.  I sent an email to 'myemailaddress@gmail.com` and `my.email.address@gmail.com (I sent it to myself).  I received a single email, and Google, indicated within the header of the email the following: "my.email.address@gmai.com (Yes, this is you.)"

Comment: OK
I confirm for my surprise that dots don't make any difference to gmail. I use my own gmail address that has dots, I try to login without dots and voilá....surprise!!!
Anyway my sister already chat with the other part and trace the problem to a common mistype mistake.